# Convert pseudocode into Wolfram Language

Tags: plotting, core-language

Pseudocode:

```
for j equals one to m 
  for k equals one to n
    put U equals j minus k.
    If the absolute value of U is less than or equals 5  
      plot the point (j, k).
```

where `m` and `n` are positive integers say 10 and 15,

How can I code this in the Wolfram Language?

Comment: If the absolute value of U is less than or equals to 5 ( not one),  then plot the point (j,k)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even straightforward `For` and friends? p.s. take a look at `Table`.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Mathematica5, I want to plot these points using ListPlot, it gave the following message: ListPlot::list: List expected at position 1 in ListPlot[Catenate[{{{1, 1}, \
{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}}, \[LeftSkeleton]8\[RightSkeleton], \
{{10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}, {10, 9}, {10, 10}, {10, 11}, {10, 12}, \
{10, 13}, {10, 14}, {10, 15}}}]]

Comment: Try to replace `Catenate[...]` by `Join@@(...)`. `Catenate` was introduced in version 10.

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since roughly `(2 max + 1) m` points have to be generated with `max` probably significantly smaller than `n`, it is rather inefficient to run a double for-loop over the full range from `1` to `m` and `1` to `n` (this would have complexity `m n`. So here is my proposal:

```
Catenate[
 Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, m}, {j, Max[1, i - max], Min[n, i + max]}]
 ]
```

Already with `m = 10`, `n = 15` and `max = 5`, this is five times faster than doing the double loop as in [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066)'s answer (which I do not mean to discredit in any way---I'd rather say that the *given pseudocode* is inefficient):

```
m = 10;
n = 15;
max = 5;

a = Catenate[
     Table[If[Abs[j - k] <= max, {j, k}, Nothing], {j, m}, {k, n}]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Catenate[
     Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, m}, {j, Max[1, i - max], Min[n, i + max]}]
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.000196
>
> 0.0000376
>
> True

With `m = 1000`, `n = 1500` and `max = 5`, this would be already about 400 times faster. Compiling this to C with `Compile` can speed this up even further (by a factor of 20) but that's another story and not precisely about the core language.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I wouldn't recommend using nested For-loops as your pseudocode suggests. Rather, I would suggest using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) (because it a very basic Wolfram Language function that every beginner should learn to use) and then reduce the resulting table to a list of pairs with [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) The plotting can be done with [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). Like so:

```
pts =
  With[{m = 10, n = 15, max = 5},
    Table[If[Abs[j - k] <= max, {j, k}, Nothing], {j, m}, {k, n}] // Catenate];

ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"m", "n"}]
```

[image: plot]

This method also works but may be a little harder for a beginner to understand.

```
pts =
  With[{m = 10, n = 15, max = 5},
    Array[If[Abs[#1 - #2] <= max, {#1, #2}, Nothing] &, {m, n}]] // Catenate;
```

#### Update

This update addresses an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

Mathematica 5. Oh,my! That is a very old version. Much has changed and much has been added since. Here are two ways to make the points that might work for you.

Neither `None` nor `Catenate` were available until fairly recently, which is why my code doesn't work for you.

I'm pretty sure that this will work in V5 -- AFAIK it uses nothing that wasn't available in V3.5, which is the oldest version I have experience with.

```
pts =
  With[{m = 10, n = 15, max = 5}, 
    DeleteCases[ 
      Flatten[Table[If[Abs[j - k] <= max, {j, k}, Null], {j, m}, {k, n}], 1], 
      Null]]
```

`Pick` was introduced in V5.1, so maybe this will also work.

```
pts =
  With[{m = 10, n = 15, max = 5},
    Module[{table},
      table =
        Flatten[Table[If[Abs[j - k] <= max, {j, k}, Null], {j, m}, {k, n}], 1];
      Pick[table, table, {_, _}]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using Mathematica 5, I can not get the plot. It gave this message: ListPlot::list: List expected at position 1 in ListPlot[Catenate[{{{1, 1}, \
{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, \
Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing}, \
\[LeftSkeleton]9\[RightSkeleton]}], AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {m, n}]. What should I do to get the plot as in your answer?

Comment: Can confirm, the last snippet [works in version 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAp0J.png).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for confirming. I'm surprised to learn that you have a running copy of V5 available to you. Do you use it for anything other the performing regression tests on code?

Comment: @M.Ali. I have updated my answer to address your issue.

Comment: It's more like I have a friend with a version 5 installation who lets me access his computer remotely. :) It's also useful for opening old notebooks I hadn't yet converted completely, and to check integration-related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
With[{m = 10, n = 15}, 
    Outer[
        Function[{j, k}, If[Abs[j - k] <= 5, {j, k}, Nothing]], 
        Range[m], 
        Range[n]]
] // Flatten[#, 1] & // ListPlot
```

for old versions of Mathematica (before `Nothing` was added in v10.2), this should work:

```
With[{m = 10, n = 15}, 
    Outer[
        Function[{j, k}, If[Abs[j - k] <= 5, {j, k}, Nothing]], 
        Range[m], 
        Range[n]]
] // Flatten[#, 1] & // DeleteCases[#, Nothing] & // ListPlot
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using Mathematica 5, when I run this code it gave this message:ListPlot::lpn: {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, Nothing, \
Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, \[LeftSkeleton]127\
\[RightSkeleton], {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}, {10, 9}, {10, 10}, {10, \
11}, {10, 12}, {10, 13}, {10, 14}, {10, 15}} is not a list of numbers or \
pairs of numbers.

Comment: Just updated my answer. I think it will now work with version 5.2.